# I am using node.js and this was a preset, yet it doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, discord.js

I am using node.js for a discord bot. I tried to use virustotals api and modify it so the output shows in command, but im just getting errors that it could not find the site because it was encrypted by the code, but if i remove the encryption from the code, it doesn't want to callback therefore it doesn't work, does anything seem to be wrong? ive tried asking a few friends who know 1 or 2 things about javascript but he can't find it out either. What the bot does it that it takes the website you put in, and send it to the urllookup from virustotal, then it sends the request back to my command prompt, which i am going to try and program it to say it inside of a bot but thats a whole 'nother thing. (I use ?(website name) to activate the bots code, so ?google.com)

```
var nvt = require('node-virustotal');
var defaultTimedInstance = nvt.makeAPI();
var hashed = nvt.sha256(args[0].substr(1));
theSameObject = defaultTimedInstance.urlLookup(nvt.sha256(args[0].substr(1)), function(err, res) {
if (err) {
    console.log('Well, crap.');
    console.log(err);
    return;
}
    console.log(JSON.parse(res).data.attributes.last_analysis_stats);
    return;
```

This isn't urgent, im just questioning why this doesn't work.

The error I get when I run it normally and enter "test.com"

```
    "error": {
        "code": "NotFoundError",
        "message": "URL \"8a783b9b3ea9dd31be0244e76159fb35143e703d9f0d672f40d3d348b249f5c0\" not found"
    }
}
```

The error I get if I try and remove the hash function

```
callback(body);
                        ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Comment: You should post the error you're getting.

Comment: done, i have added the errors i get in console to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the urllookup to domainlookup which allowed me to remove the hash, which also fixed it, thanks!